# WPF Screen Resolution Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Our wpf window application best fit resolution is 1920 * 1080. But we can't expect the same resolution in all machines. Most of the people still using low resolutions.

Now the machine in low resolution our application have lot of scroll bars. My question is without any scroll bars, possible for Zoom In /Zoom Out Wpf application based on machine resolution.

Comment: In case if you zoom out, then you may not be able to read the UI text know??

Answer (score 1):

use ViewBox

```
<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Grid control with relative column width and row height is the solution. This way control width and height can be flexible. Instead of using fixed width and height you can use VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" which basically makes the control’s size same as the grid cell.  You will also not see any scrollbar. However it’s a good idea to set MinWidth and MinHeight to the control according to the lowest resolution you want to support. For example-

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```